# Determine when an equation has no more than one zero on an interval.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am curious as to how to find where an equation like $x^3 -28x + c = 0$ that has only one zero from $[-4,4]$ does not exist.  I want to know how to solve for the interval of c that satisfies/breaks the equation.  How do you calculate the min/max $c$ value where there is a zero in the limited domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular equation, if c is very large the only solution will be less than -4; likewise if c is very large negative the only solution will be greater than 4. As c increases from large negative values the first value of c giving another solution will be when a turning point touches the x-axis. This may or may not be before the low part of the cubic curve comes into [-4,4].

You need to find the values of c when x=4 and x=-4, and if the turning points are in [-4,4] (for this equation they are) you also need the values of c when the turning points are on the x-axis.

There is at least one solution in [-4,4] when c is anywhere from the smallest of these 4 values of c to the largest.

Comment: That definiately worked thank you!